# How to refresh TableView after deleting data from it?

Tags: java, javafx, refresh, tableview

How to refresh TableView after deleting data from it ?
*(I have to click on the row and then on the deleteButton, to delete)*

Here is where I delete the data form the Observable-List:

```
  @FXML
    void delAction(ActionEvent event) {
            fnlData.remove(index);  //fnl Data is the Observable List
            finalTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(); //finalTable ist the TableView

    }

    public final void select() {
        finalTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldvalue, Object newValue) {
                setIndex(fnlData.indexOf(newValue));
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you haven't shown. If everything is set up correctly, these calls will automatically cause the table to update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I fixed it...

Here is the code:

```
@FXML
    void delAction(ActionEvent event) {
            fnlData.remove(index);
            finalTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        finalTable.getItems().clear();
        finalTable.getItems().addAll(fnlData);
    }
```

Comment: If `fnlData` is not a reference to the items in the table (which I assume it isn't, given this answer), why not just do `finalTable.getItems().remove(index);` instead of all that code?

Comment: Oh ok :)
but what do u mean with "fnlData is not a reference to the items in the table" ?

Comment: `fnlData == finalTable.getItems()` is `false` (check it). If at some point you have called `finalTable.setItems(fnlData)` then it would be `true`, and just calling `fnlData.remove(index)` would work (it would be identical to `finalTable.getItems().remove(index)`, of course).